# Angular is stuck on "reloading client(s)" and not refreshing the page

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, refresh

Im starting a tutorial on angular (i'm a react dev) and I simply created a new project with "ng new my-first-app". The thing is that hot module reload for some reason stops working just a few seconds after I start modifying for example the "app-component.html" with various random texts inside a html element ex "\<h1\>Hello dsdhs shdsd {{title}}\</h1\>" and I can't figure out why, and then I have to do ctrl+c and re-run in order to see the latest changes. In the terminal i can see "reloading client" when that happens:

`Unchanged output files: 2 Application bundle generation complete. [0.112 seconds] Reloading client(s)... `

Could this be a problem related to v17 of angular? If yes, then how can I downgrade easily let's say to v16 for all the dependencies related to angular?

For more information:

- I am using node v20.9.0 and npm v10.2.3
- please check the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-first-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "rxjs": "\~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "\~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "\~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "\~5.1.0",
    "karma": "\~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "\~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "\~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "\~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "\~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "\~5.2.2"
  }
}
```

And also this is the tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": \[
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    \]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A fix has landed in `17.0.6` do it solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an angular version issue which is pending to be fixed, downgrading to the previous one (16.2.0) did not reproduce the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, re-serving the application eliminates the issue temporarily.

I also suspect that this is a bug, and expect / hope for it to get fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other 2 answers. I have the same issue on Angular version 17.0.0.

Only workaround I see for now would be to re-serve your app.

I see that you also mentioned wanting to downgrade. Since you just started and wanted to play around with Angular, you could just completely uninstall and reinstall an earlier version.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli

npm cache clean

npm install -g angular-cli@your_desired_version
```

Something along these lines should do the trick. I bet there are some other ways where you just downgrade the cli and update the project config accordingly but I don't really think it makes sense in your case.